# Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint' when linting and 'plugin:prettier/recommended' is enabled in eslitrc.js

Tags: typescript, eslint, prettier

I have a node project using nestjs and eslint_d for linting. My eslint.js file looks like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir : __dirname,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],

...
```

when I disable the line 'plugin:prettier/recommended' I can run eslint_d without a problem, but if I run it for a file with that line enabled I get the following output:

```
.../app/documents/documents.controller.ts
Error: Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint'
Require stack:
- /.../node_modules/prettier/index.js
- /.../node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier.js
- /.../node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs
Occurred while linting /.../src/<MYPROJECT>/src/.../app/documents/xxx.controller.ts:1
Rule: "prettier/prettier"
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The plugin looks like it's installed. Can anyone help?

I tried enabling debugging but couldn't get better output. Disabling the plugin is a workaround. Happy to answer any other questions.

Comment: Make sure that you have the latest version of the @typescript-eslint plugin and the eslint-plugin-prettier plugin installed in your project.

Comment: That seems to have done it. Thank you.